# How to show custom date format in angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker input field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker for date time selection. I want to show dates in moment format "MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a"("December 22nd 2016, 2:00 pm"). Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by custom format ? Can you please mention the format in which you want ?

Comment: moment format "MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation [here](https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

You can pass configuration options as a function or an object.

```
Selected Date: {{ data.date | date:'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a' }}

<datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.embeddedDate"
    data-datetimepicker-config="{ startView:'day', minView:'day' }" />
```

Comment: How to configure localDateValue in DateObject??

Answer (score 0):

You can defined the angular bootstrap format like :

```
uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
```

format which you want to show like

```
uib-datepicker-popup="MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/), I refered

You can take a look at the documentation if required

```
Selected Date: {{ data.date | date:'MMMM Do YYYY, shortTime' }}

<datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.embeddedDate"
    data-datetimepicker-config="{ startView:'day', minView:'day' }" />
```